# Tree view in sencha-touch

Tags: treeview, tree, sencha-touch, extjs, treepanel

I want to create a tree panel in sencha touch, but I am unable to find a single example the net and on the sencha website also, istead I got one in ext js 4, but I need to create it in sencha touch only. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a construct called the NestedList, which seems similar. It doesn't have as much granularity as the extjs treepanel seems to have, however.

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/1-1/#!/api/Ext.NestedList
http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.dataview.NestedList